# how to update localstorage value?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Here is the origin json set in the local storage

```
"profiles": [
    "headers":[
        "key": "val"
        "value": false
    ]
]
```

And I've got the value of the header which is **false** from the console by the following code

```
chrome.storage.local.get(['profiles'], function(p){console.log(p['profiles'][0]['headers'][0]['value'])})
```

Now I would like to update the header's value to **true** in this case

I've tried both modified the value from get() callback and use the chrome.storage.local.set()
But none of them are working.

Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
localStorage.setItem('key','value')
```

to update local storage.